# how to delete the results of a complex query

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I replace `select *` with `delete` I get a syntax error on line 2 near t. But I need that t, because I'm referencing it in the where clause. So how do I delete the results of this query?

```
select *
    from [PrimusGroup].[dbo].[PrmsBlotter] t
    where t.RunType = 'Backtesting'
      and not exists (
        select 1
        from [PrimusGroup].[dbo].[PrmsBlotter] i
        where i.RunType = 'Live'
          and i.BBox = t.BBox
          and convert(date,i.RunDateStart) = convert(date,t.TestDateFrom)
    )
```

Comment: Replace it with `delete t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gordon Linoff said, replace the `select *` with `delete t`.

```
delete t
from [PrimusGroup].[dbo].[PrmsBlotter] t
where t.RunType = 'Backtesting'
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from [PrimusGroup].[dbo].[PrmsBlotter] i
    where i.RunType = 'Live'
      and i.BBox = t.BBox
      and convert(date,i.RunDateStart) = convert(date,t.TestDateFrom)
)
```